# How do I login to outlook.com with IMAP using MailKit?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, imap, mailkit, outlook.com

I'm attepting to use MailKit to access the emails in my personal outlook.com account.

I'm using the IMAP settings recommended by Microsoft but when I call `_imapClient.Authenticate` with my username and password I get a 'LOGON failed' exception returned.

A few sites have directed me to use `Oauth2` to authenticate but this requires I register my app in the Azure portal which I don't have access to. My account being a personal one.

```
        private ImapClient _imapClient;
        private MailboxConfiguration _mailboxConfiguration;

        public ConfiguredMailbox(MailboxConfiguration mailboxConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        { 
            _mailboxConfiguration = mailboxConfiguration;
            _imapClient = new ImapClient();
            _imapClient.Connect(_mailboxConfiguration.URL, _mailboxConfiguration.Port, true, cancellationToken);

            _imapClient.Authenticate(_mailboxConfiguration.Username, _mailboxConfiguration.Password, cancellationToken);
            _imapClient.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite, cancellationToken);
        }
```

If I've previously logged in with a browser, this will work for about a minute.
I'm guessing that the token issued to the browser is also being used.

I did try implemeting the `Oauth2` method suggested but I just got an error basically saying you can't do this for MSA accounts.